# Interior weather proofing for historic warehouse windows?

Tags: windows

I live in a converted warehouse and the windows are over 100 years old. Rolled metal frame with single pane windows, in a brick wall. They are quite drafty and have poor sound insulation. You can see the windows in this photo

[image]

We have custom powered shades that roll down and fill the window frame (they are up in this photo).

I'm trying to think through the best way to insulate them from the interior for the winter - ideally something I can remove for the warmer months to maintain the view and use of the pivot window in the center.

Challenges

- Historic building so we can't change the design of the windows. We
  must maintain the facade of he building that includes the window
  design.
- The windows are 17x7.5ft and 15x7.5ft. The large size makes it near impossible to find off the shelf solutions, so it will need to
  be custom.
- I used Frost King (https://www.homedepot.com/p/Frost-King-Indoor-Window-Insulation-Kit-3-per-Pack-V73-3H/100135637) last year, which was a pain to install given the size of the windows, and having to stitch together two sheets per
  window. They worked somewhat but were more a headache and eyesore
  than the bit of draft they blocked.
- Restoration of these windows is very costly and ideally I can push that cost out for a few more years. Plus we are on the 4th floor
  above a major street, so any exterior work will have more challenges.

I live in Northern Georgia. I've talked to neighbors and some have put up heavy blackout curtains to block the wind and temp loss, others have caulked all parts of their window and made them unable to open. the rest just deal with the draftiness.

Comment: Recommendations of companies is explicitly [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), so you should [edit] that part out. Do you have a specific question you're looking to get answered?

Comment: Caulking around the windows plus weather stripping where they open.  The outside edges(inside) might need insulation/spray foam for sealing.

Comment: I've inlined the image to prevent link-rot (& removed the service recommendation). Good pic, btw. Takes some effort to shoot through a window & get the light right. btw, HomeDepot is geofenced [pointlessly but annoyingly], so people outside US/Ca can't see the links.

Answer (score 1):

Double or triplewall plastic greenhouse glazing. You'll have no view for the winter, but it does work. Coroplast also works, but transmits a lot less light - but may be cheaper. Put it over the whole window opening onto the wall surface for best results.

I had a mill space in a more northerly clime for a few years.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted towards using three perspex sheets per window, aligned to the exiting 3-section appearance.

Tape the outer edges with neoprene foam strip to give them a very slight grip force to the frames, but hold them in place with small wooden [possibly black-painted] 'keys' at each corner, for minimal visual impact.
Tape the joins between each section.

That way you're not trying to find storage for a pair of huge & delicate 17' sheets every year; you could at a push leave the side two panels of each in situ in summer, removing only the centre to allow ventilation.
If you were to consider that, you could then caulk those two outer panels to the walls, & also to the frames themselves, semi-permanently.